# displaying other database values in another form when id number is selected in previous form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to show other details to another form when id number is selected in previous form?

this is a picture of my previous form: [image]

and this is `part of my code` where it displays on the textboxes whenever the row is clicked:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                textBox2.Text = row.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
                textBox3.Text = row.Cells["lastname"].Value.ToString();
                textBox4.Text = row.Cells["firstname"].Value.ToString(); 
            }
        }
```

What I want is to show more details to another form which is viewed like this:
[image]

problem is i dont know how to make a syntax out of this. Can you help me or at least give me an idea on how to make the second form work?

Comment: Create a global variable called `currentID` that you `set` when the user selects a row on `Form1`. On `Form2`'s `Load` event, you can `get` `currentID` and load appropriate data. If it were me, I'd add a class called `Global.cs` and have a variable called `public static string currentID` (or whatever type you're using; example given going by your code above).

Comment: @TestWell can I use something like this? public Form2(string strTextBox)
 {
      InitializeComponent();
      label1.Text=strTextBox;
 }

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea,

```
//event on which you want to show new form
{
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            textBox2.Text = row.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = row.Cells["lastname"].Value.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = row.Cells["firstname"].Value.ToString(); 
            Form Form2=new Form(row);
            Form2.Show();
            //can use Form2.ShowDialog(); according to requirements
        }
 }

//Constructor of form 2 

public Form2(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    tbx1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    tbx2.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

}
```

Comment: only the values in datagridview would appear on second form. ive tried it already. what i want is all information of a certain employee would appear on the other form.